# How to filter rows in a dataframe to get only 3 most popular and delete others unused data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Theory**
I have some data on car brands in the US. I have to arrange them on the map of individual states and after hovering over with the mouse, I have to display the 3 most popular brands for a given state.

---

**Question**
I have the following dataframe

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1  20   0  40  10  30
2   0  60  15   5  20 
3  50  30  20   0   0
```

I need to achieve something like that (structure is probably wrong - I am not sure what kind of structure would be best - I just need data about name of column and its value):

```
1  (C: 40) (E: 30) (A: 20)
2  (B: 60) (E: 20) (C: 15)
3  (A: 50) (B: 30) (C: 20)
```

---

**Current situation**
I was able to create something like this:

```
pd.crosstab(df['code'],df['brand'],normalize='index').reset_index(drop=True).apply(lambda x: x*100)
```

[image]

So the situation is identical to the example I gave at the top. Now I have to somehow "filter this data and keep information about the brand name and its percentage in a given state".

---

It is a bit difficult for me, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and convert it to a dictionary:

```
res = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).nlargest(3).to_dict(), axis=1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0    {'C': 40, 'E': 30, 'A': 20}
1    {'B': 60, 'E': 20, 'C': 15}
2    {'A': 50, 'B': 30, 'C': 20}
dtype: object
```

If order is *really* important, return a list:

```
res = df.apply(lambda x: list(pd.Series(x).nlargest(3).items()), axis=1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0    [(C, 40), (E, 30), (A, 20)]
1    [(B, 60), (E, 20), (C, 15)]
2    [(A, 50), (B, 30), (C, 20)]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly. I did not even know that it can put into the dictionary so easily. Thanks boss!!! You saved me :D

Comment: @Harord Glad I could help ;)